# How to lock table in sequelize, wait until another request to be complete

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**Description:**

I have one table in db say `Table1`. having only one column `AppNo(numeric)` and only single row, and current value is `0`

I have created API in `node.js` using `Sequelize` ORM named `UpdateAppNo`.

Whenever `UpdateAppNo` api called value of `AppNo` should increment by `1`.

**What i want:**

If 2 or more simultaneous request comes at a time, current request should wait until previous request to complete.

**What happening now:**

If previous request is in process, then current request throws an error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you want is a [Transaction](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions) that wraps your `.findXX` query which uses a [`lock`](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/#locks) option to turn it into a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement.

The find query with the `lock` option will lock the row (you don't need to lock the entire table) and because you are using a transaction, the action will either be committed or rolled back depending on whether or not your instance holds the lock.

You will want to adapt the code found in [these](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/#locks) examples for your use.

```js
return User.findAll({
  limit: 1,
  lock: true, // <-- this does the trick
  transaction: t1
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, can we have live example for this...it will be help full.

Comment: @PiyushDhamecha have you find a working solution in the end?

Comment: none of the links work now and without them this answer is meaningless

Comment: Here's the link to locks: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/#locks

Answer (score 20):

This is old, but also the first google hit, so I'm posting this in case others have stumbled here.

As Chase said this is not at all well documented. Here's some code that will do what you want...

```js
const User = db.User

const t = await sequelize.transaction(async(t) => {
  const user = await User.findByPk(userId, {lock: true, transaction: t})
  user.fieldToIncrement++
  await user.save({transaction:t})
})
```

Key points:

1. This code example is using the "Managed" transaction provided by Sequelize, so you don't need to manually manage commit/rollback, however the same will work with unmanaged transactions
2. **You need to provide the lock option as well as the transaction**, otherwise the transaction occurs without the lock you are looking for. Requests to update the table row while it's locked will balk until the lock is released.
3. **Don't forget to include the transaction object** in the options for any database actions inside the transaction context (see the call to user.save() ), otherwise your transaction will balk on itself...

I hope that's helpful to someone!

Comment: If another process already locks the row is the transaction commit will wait until the lock is released or will it fail?